# Can not remove an object into a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't know how to remove an object from an `ArrayList`. I know there is remove but in my case, its more complicate.

I have a `ArrayList` (listsBlocksRemaining), which contains object that I put into another `ArrayList` (listBlocksIntoRibbon) when there are print. Then, what I want, its that the object that are print should be removed from listBlocksRemaining, there are print so no more remaining.

This is my code :

```
public void algoGlouton(Graphics g) {

    int offsetX = 13;
    int offsetY = 600;
    int widthAvailable= 0;
    int smallestHeight= 300;
    for(Bloc b : listsBlocksRemaining) {
        if(widthRemaining+b.getWidth () < ribbon.getWidth ()) {
            widthAvailable+= b.getWidth();
             g.setColor(b.getColor());
             g.fillRect(offsetX, offsetY-b.getHeight(), b.getWidth(), b.getHauteur());
             listBlocksIntoRibbon.add(b);
             b.setX(offsetX);
             b.setY(offsetY-b.getHauteur());
             offsetX += b.getLargeur();
        } else {
            for(Bloc b1 : listBlocksIntoRibbon) {
                if(b1.getHauteur() < smallestHeight) {
                    smallestHeight= b1.getHeight();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this :

```
for(int i = 0; i<listsBlocksRemaining.size();i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<listBlocksIntoRibbon.size();j++) {
            if(listsBlocksRemaining.get(i) == listBlocksIntoRibbon.get(j)) {
                listsBlocksRemaining.remove(i);
            }
        }
}
```

and this :

```
for(int i = 0; i<listsBlocksRemaining.size();i++) {
        Bloc b = listsBlocksRemaining.get(i);
        if(listBlocksIntoRibbon.equals(b)) {
            listsBlocksRemaining.remove(b);
        }
}
```

Cordially

Comment: I prefer to override equals() and hashCode() methods in Bloc and then just call listsBlocksRemaining.remove(b)

Comment: @istovatis what do you mean ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to remove all the elements of listBlocksIntoRibbon from listsBlocksRemaining, right? `listsBlocksRemaining.removeAll(listBlocksIntoRibbon)` does that. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-

Comment: First of all thanks for your help, but what I want is that when a block has been placed into the listBlocksIntoRibbon I instantly delete it from listBlocksRemaining, with what you said, it'll cause an Exception.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find the object in `listBlocksRemaining` in order to remove it.  You can just remove the object from the list as:

```
for( Bloc bloc : listBlocksIntoRibbon )
  listBlocksRemaining.remove(bloc);
```

or even:

```
listBlocksRemaining.removeAll( listBlocksIntoRibbon );
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your help, but what I want is that when a block has been placed into the `listBlocksIntoRibbon` I instantly delete it from `listBlocksRemaining`, with what you said, it'll cause an Exception.

Comment: Then right after you do `listBlocksIntoRibbon.add(b);`, just do `listBlocksRemaining.remove(b);`, but you should loop through listsBlocksRemaining with an iterator and not a for loop.

Comment: If you want to instantly remove it from the list you are iterating over, you need to use an actual Iterator, and call `remove()` on the iterator after you add it to `listBlocksIntoRibbon`.

Comment: Yes, I've just see someone put an anwser with a Iterator, but there is still a problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, its what I did, but i've still an error.. could I give you my project (eclipse) and check why its not doint it correctly please ?

Answer (score 0):

To safely remove from a collection while iterating over it you should use an Iterator.

Try this:

```
 Iterator<Bloc> itr = listsBlocksRemaining.iterator();
 while(itr.hasNext()){
      Bloc b = itr.next();
      ...
       listBlocksIntoRibbon.add(b);
       itr.remove();
       ...
 }
```

Comment: My bad, I import the wrong thing.. thanks, i'll try now